# sitemap trimming is not working

Tags: asp.net, web-config, sitemap

I have read up on articles and done a lot of research but this is kicking my butt and it should be easy. I'm hoping its easy to fix.

Im trying to trim my sitemap based on roles however the menu control never changes.

**Sitemap:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0">  
    <siteMapNode url="#" title="Home" description="Home">  
        <siteMapNode url="~/default.aspx" title="Dashboard"  description="" roles="Administrator, Tech, Basic" />  
        <siteMapNode url="Referrel" title="Referral"  description="" roles="Administrator, Tech, Basic">  
            <siteMapNode url="referral-new.aspx" title="New"  description="" roles="Administrator, Tech" />        
            <siteMapNode url="referrals-all.aspx" title="All"  description="" roles="Administrator, Tech, Basic" />  
        </siteMapNode>  
        <siteMapNode url="~/reports/default.aspx" title="Reports" description="" roles="CEO" />  
    </siteMapNode>  
</siteMap>
```

**web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>

  </configSections>

  <appSettings>

    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;url=~/temp"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=;User ID=;Password=;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <!--
Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging
symbols into the compiled page. Because this
affects performance, set this value to true only
during development.
-->
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="20000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="20" name="eReferral" requireSSL="false" defaultUrl="default.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users = "?"/>
    </authorization>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider" description="Default SiteMap provider." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
      </providers>
    </siteMap>

    <!--
The <customErrors> section enables configuration
of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs
during the execution of a request. Specifically,
it enables developers to configure html error pages
to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
<error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
<error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
</customErrors>
-->
    <pages theme="Clean">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*"/>
      <add path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      <add path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      <add path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      <add path="BarcodeGen.axd" verb="*" type="Neodynamic.WebControls.BarcodeProfessional.BarcodeProfessional, Neodynamic.WebControls.BarcodeProfessional"/>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access -->

  <location path="forgot-password.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>


  <!-- Referral Folder -->
  <location path="referral/referral-new.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Tech"/>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="referral/referral-details.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator, Basic, Tech, Physician"/>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="referral/referral-new.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator, Basic, Tech, Physician"/>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Reports/default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="CEO"/>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>


  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <!--
The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
Information Services 7.0. It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
-->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <add name="BarcodeGen" path="BarcodeGen.axd" verb="*" type="Neodynamic.WebControls.BarcodeProfessional.BarcodeProfessional, Neodynamic.WebControls.BarcodeProfessional"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"/>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: looks like i cant add the sitemap code

Comment: Formatting fixed. Enjoy!

Comment: thanks man...how did you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try putting this too in the site map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
  <siteMapNode url="" title="Secciones"  description="" roles="Admin,Users">
    <siteMapNode url="~/p_Site/Cursos.aspx" title="Cursos"  description="Information" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/p_Site/Precios.aspx" title="Prices"  description="All the Prices" />
  </siteMapNode>

  <siteMapNode url="" title="Administration"  description="" roles="Admin">
    <siteMapNode url="~/p_Admin/Alumnos.aspx" title="Debt List"/>
    <siteMapNode url="~/p_Admin/Pagos.aspx" title="Pay List"  description="" />
  </siteMapNode>

</siteMapNode>
```

I have specified the roles allowed to each part of the site.map, and that plus the Web.Config entry you have, should work ;)

Best Regards!!!

C

Comment: i tried a slimmed down version of the sitemap...just 2 nodes for roles im not a member of and they show up.

Comment: I deleted the sitemap and started from scratch and changed the default proivder name to 'default' and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , Solution :
In my case  i have not provided outer siteMapNode  roles :)

```
<siteMapNode roles ="admin"> this is outer 
<siteMapNode roles ="admin" /> inner
<siteMapNode roles ="admin"/> inner
</siteMapNode>
```